# How we can add "buy now" on our templete file from wordpress woocommerce plugin?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add a **buy now** button with every product that took the user to the paypal page or checkout page.
Inside woocommerce documentation, I'm unable to find any shortcode or filter. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i used the following code in my theme's `functions.php` file:

```
    add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','nom_buy_now_after_add_to_cart_button');

    function nom_buy_now_after_add_to_cart_button(){
        function nom_buy_now_after_add_to_cart_button(){ 
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
            $('.buy-now').on('click',function(e){
                $('#buy-now-field').val('1');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <input type="hidden" name="nom_buy_now_field" id="buy-now-field" value="">
    <?php
    echo '<button type="submit" data-product-id="'.get_the_ID().'" class="button buy-now" style="margin-left:4px;">'. apply_filters('nom_woocommerce_buy_now_button_text', 'Buy Now') .'</button>';
}
        echo '<button type="submit" data-product-id="'.get_the_ID().'" class="button buy-now" style="margin-left:4px;">'. apply_filters('nom_woocommerce_buy_now_button_text', 'Buy Now') .'</button>';
    }
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'nom_buy_now_after_add_to_cart_redirect_to_checkout');

    function nom_buy_now_after_add_to_cart_redirect_to_checkout() {
        global $woocommerce;

        $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();    
        if( isset($_REQUEST['nom_buy_now_field']) ){
            return $checkout_url;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works only on singe product for me, how can I customize It for shop page as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Product type `External/Affiliate Product` will work for you.

Create a new product & change its product type to `External/Affiliate Product` from product type drop down box. OR you can also change product type of existing product.

In `General` tab, find 2 fields - `Product URL` and `Button Text`

`Product URL` - will be your PayPal link
`Button text` - will appear on the button on Product shop page

Save changes.

Does this answers your query?